# to_char equivalent mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with the equivalent `to_char` from SQL to MySQL this is pretty much what I am trying to do

```
SELECT to_char(cus_inf.column1) no_operation
```

I need to convert this to MySQL column1 is from a table called `cus_inf`

thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL will usually convert to character automatically when necessary. What are you doing that requires explicit conversion?

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `cast()`?

```
select cast(cus_inf.column1 as char) as no_operation
```